# Why do we need hidden values?

Tags: php, forms

Been studying PhP lately but im stump about hidden values for example:

```
if (isset($_POST['userid']))
{
    $userid = $_POST['userid'];
} else {
    $userid = '';
}

if (isset($_POST['password']))
{
    $password = $_POST['password'];
} else {
    $password = '';
}

if (isset($_POST['userid']))
{
    print "<input type='hidden' name='userid' size='11' value='".$userid."' /><br /> ";
    print "<input type='hidden' name='password' size='11' value='".$password."' /><br /> ";
} else {

    print "<h2>Enter UserId/Password to Login: </h2>";

    print "<table> ";

    print "<tr> ";
    print "<td>User ID</td><td><input type='text' name='userid' size='11' /><br /> ";
    print "</tr> ";

    print "<tr> ";
    print "<td>Password</td><td><input type='password' name='password' size='11' /></td> ";
    print "</tr> ";

    print "</table> ";

    print "<p><input type='submit' name='mysubmit' value='Login' /> ";

    print "</form></body></html>";

    exit;
```

I dont understand  the purpose for the hidden value. according to this website, it is for the form to validate but wouldnt it validate the input that the user inserted?

could someone explain it to me?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense anyway. Hidden fields are used to sent the unique id to the script to update or delete something in your database. But doesn't have necessary to be in a database. It could be in a file as well.

Comment: Never ever send passwords back to the browser: Validate the session on the server as soon as it is sent the first time (using sessions) and then forget about the password.

Answer (score 2):

hidden inputs are for values that you already have, and you don't need the user to insert them.

Let's say you have a site where users add their own products, when a user wants to edit a product of his, you need to send the product id in your database along with the form to know which product the user is editing, at the same time, the user doesn't even have an idea what is the product id so you pass it as a hidden input.

the post you showed doesn't really make sense, maybe you are checking a website that is bad or contains outdated information.

I hope that's clear.